# Laravel - Insert post id to another table on publish

Tags: php, laravel

When I publish a post using store method in Laravel, I want to insert the id of the publishing post to another table right after. How is this possible?

Comment: You should have tried something, can you show us what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = new Data;
    // Add other data
    $data->save();

    // Now you can get the last inserted id
    $last_id = $data->id;

    // Or 
    $last_id_2 = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    // For that, dont forget to add DB class

}
```